# Ordered union query with pagination

Tags: sql-server, pagination

For one query this one works fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
   ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_article DESC) AS RowNum, 
            id_article, 
            article_name, ... 
     FROM articles 
) AS  RowConstrainedResult  
WHERE RowNum >=0 
      AND 
      RowNum <= 20 
ORDER BY  RowNum
```

Now I need union first query with another from same table order them by date and paginate result.

```
SELECT  articles.id_article AS ID, 
        articles.article_name AS NAME,
        articles.article_dateNew AS DATE 
FROM articles 
UNION 
SELECT  free_arts.id_art AS ID, 
        free_arts.art_name AS NAME, 
        free_arts.art_dateNew AS DATE 
FROM free_arts 
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
(
     Select V1.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS RowNum
     From
       (
          SELECT  articles.id_article AS ID, 
                  articles.article_name AS NAME,
                  articles.article_dateNew AS DATE 
          FROM articles 
          UNION -- All
          SELECT free_arts.id_art AS ID, 
                 free_arts.art_name AS NAME, 
                 free_arts.art_dateNew AS DATE 
          FROM free_arts               
        ) as V1           
  )
WHERE RowNum >=0 
      AND
      RowNum <= 20 
--ORDER BY  RowNum
```

Comment: thanks for a comment, but now it return an error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Welcome to the wiki pal. I made a update to my answer, may come in handy. You may transfer your ordering logic to ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)

Comment: @IgorIvanov ,i think Instead Of Union ,Union All should be use because both Table are different so both id mean different thing.Also if you are using Sql Server 2012 or above then you can use OffSet,which can reduce your one select statement,thus increase in performance.